# Can't put Python 3.7.3 in the Windows 10 path

Tags: windows, python

I want to be able to use Python in my command prompt. I looked up a bunch of tutorials that told me to copy paste the application path (`C:\Users\Merih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python`) into the "Path" section in the system variables menu. I did that exactly but it didn't work. When I try to use Python in the command prompt it gives the error message:

```
python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I supposed to do?

Screenshot of what I did:

[image: Screenshot of what I did]

Answer (score 1):

You want to put the *directory* that the *python.exe* executable resides in.

Try changing it from:

`C:\Users\Merih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python`

to

`C:\Users\Merih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\`

Comment: I did what you said but now all that happens is when I say "**python**" it replies back with "`Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32;Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`". Other than that I still can't use python commands

Comment: I don't understand why you can't enter commands. You should see `>>>` the line after `Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`. You should be able to enter commands, such as `print("Setec Astronomy")`. Enter this into your command prompt: `pythonw.exe "C:\Users\Merih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw"`. It should launch IDLE, which you can run Python code in.

Comment: Running `python` with no arguments runs the interactive command line interpreter. If you want e.g  `python script_name.py` to work, you may need to log out (or even possibly reboot) to get your path changes to take effect.

Comment: In Windows 10, at least, any path changes take effect as soon as you restart `cmd.exe` or `python.exe`.

Comment: It all works fine now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I also had to go into Windows Settings (Winkey+I) , navigate to "Manage App Execution Aliases" , and turn off "Python Installer" , hope that helps.